# how do we differentiate a private and public API in node js

Tags: node.js

example: public api doesn't require authentication, private route should pass through middleware authentication. But how do we differentiate incoming http request is public or private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Express, there are many choices.  A simple design choice woudl be to put your private APIs on a router that has middleware that checks for authentication before routing to any of the routes and put the public APIs on a router that does not have the middleware check.  Then, the router mechanics built into Express and a properly placed middleware on the router that requires auth would do all the work for you.

Here's a simple example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const routerAuth = express.Router();
const routerPublic = express.Router();

// check auth here in the routerAuth router as the first route definition in that router
routerAuth.use((req, res, next) => {
    // check auth here
    if ( /* code here to check authorization */) {
        next();
    } else {
        // not authorized
        res.status(401).send("Not authorized");
        // or maybe just res.redirect("/login");
    }
});

// routers on routerAuth
routerAuth.get("/seeEverything", ...)
routerAuth.get("/admin", ...)

// routes on routerPublic
routerPublic.get("/", ...);
routerPublic.get("/login", ...);
routerPublic.get("/signup", ...);

// hook the routers into our server
// specify the public router first so they get a chance to be matched
// before routerAuth enforces authentication
app.use(routerPublic);
app.use(routerAuth);

app.listen(80);
```

It would be common to put each of these routers in their own module and then import them, but I've skipped that part for simplicity's sake here.  This example shows each router sharing the same path namespace, but you could also put the private router on its own path prefix if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.Can you please clarify, how will the node know that the incoming request should be passed through routerAuth or routerPubliC, Is it based on the API endpint ?.

Comment: @venkateswarluputtamsetti - There are many different ways to do it, but in this example, the public router is registered first and thus its routes get checked for a match to the incoming request BEFORE the private router.  Then, when the private router gets its chance, it enforces the authentication before it allows any route matching.  The key in Express is that routes are matched in the order they are registered.  So, here we register the public router first and thus they get a chance to match before the authorization has been checked.  Opposite for the private routes.

Comment: @venkateswarluputtamsetti - There are also many other ways to do this.  You could put the private router on it's path prefix "/admin" and it would only see routes that begin with that prefix.  That isn't required so I showed an example without doing that, but that is common too.   If you did this `app.use("/admin", routerAuth);` then all auth route would have a path prefix of `/admin` and only incoming requests that start with `/admin` would get sent to the auth router.  As I said, there are many ways to do it.

Comment: Awesome explanation, Thank you so much @jfriend00